# Lock Acquisition Order

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, thread-safety

With the following code, if a thread calls LoggingWidget.doSomething(), 
what is the order of lock acquisition that the thread has to go through?
(i.e. does it get the Lock on LoggingWidget first, and then gets the lock on Widget ? )

```
public class Widget {
   public synchronized void doSomething() {

   }
}

public class LoggingWidget extends Widget {
    public synchronized void doSomething() {
         System.out.println(toString() + ": calling doSomething");
         super.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The lock in this case is on `this` so there is only one lock, that being the instance. If there are more than one instance, each has an entirely separate lock regardless of whether it is a `Widget` or a `LoggingWidget`.

Let me put it another way. Your code is semantically equivalent to:

```
public class Widget {
  public void doSomething() {
    synchronized (this) {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}

public class LoggingWidget extends Widget {
  public void doSomething() {
    synchronized (this) {
      System.out.println(toString() + ": calling doSomething");
      super.doSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

Only one of these methods is called so there's only one lock.

Comment: The last sentence is wrong IMHO. There is only one `this` in both `doSomething()` no matter if you have a LoggingWidget or a Widget.

Comment: Yes, if you call `System.identityHashCode( this )` in both methods, you will get the same value

Answer (score 2):

**There is only one lock bcoz there is only one object**, but if the sub-class object's doSomething() method is called, the same lock is acquired twice. In JVM, the owner(thread) is same but it sets the **acquisition count** to **two**. **The acquisition count is decremented each time when the owning thread exists the synchronized block**. So here it would be decremented twice down to zero when the lock is finally released, one for each synchronized block.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, they're caleld monitors and are per object. In your example, there is only one monitor.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure you get the correct lock of type LoggingWidget and not Widget you can do this:

```
public class LoggingWidget extends Widget {
  private final Object readLock = new Object();

  public void doSomething() {
    synchronized (readLock) {
      System.out.println(toString() + ": calling doSomething");
      super.doSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

Or if you use [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org) you can just write

```
public class LoggingWidget extends Widget {
  @Synchronized("readLock")
  public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println(toString() + ": calling doSomething");
      super.doSomething();
  }
}
```